# Function to get the index of the combinations produced by itertools.product's combination/matrix representation in python?

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools

For example:

```
alist=[['a','b'],[1,2]]
```

and the combination

```
('a',1)
```

Is there a way to get the index of this combination i.e. (0,0) because both are at the 0-th position in their respective list or a matrix like

```
[[1,1],[0,0]]
```

where the 1s indicate the position get selected to form the combination?

Comment: Since `product` maps items sequentially, how is your question different to creating an object that returns the indices of a matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can just create the indices as ruaridhw pointed out. You can do it like so:

```
from itertools import product

alist = [['a','b'],[1,2]]
print [a for a in product(*alist)]
print [list(a) for a in product(*[range(len(x)) for x in alist])]
```

Output:

```
[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('b', 2)]
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
```

Comment: I got it now! It's basically the same thing but just passing the indices as input into product?

Comment: Yes. The `*` unpacking will take care of arbitrary numbers of inner lists.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Should keep this in mind. I am still new to Python but I am required to do some advanced stuffs recently hahaha.

Comment: @StanleyGan You could just generate the indices directly via `itertools.product` as so: `itertools.product(range(len(alist)), range(len(alist[0])))`

Answer (score 0):

Since each element of given combination c is to be found in the corresponding row of alist, the following returns the tuple of their indices:

```
alist = [['a','b'],[1,2]]
c = ('a',1)
ix = tuple(row.index(elem) for row, elem in zip(alist, c))
```

Here ix becomes `(0, 0)`